# How to update records based on values from another table?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I use Firebird 3.0 and I have 3 tables:

> Table1: tbl1_id (PK), f2_id (FK), tbl1_f1

tbl1_f2 is a foreign key to table2

> Table2: f2_id (PK), f3_id (FK)

f3_id is a foreign key to table3

> Table3: f3_id (PK), tbl3_code

Now I need to set Table1.tbl1_f1 = 1 where Table3.tbl3_code = 'value' so I wrote this SQL:

```
update table1 set tbl1_f1 = 1 where (tbl1_f1 is null)
and table1.tbl1_id in (

select
    tbl1_id

from table1 
   inner join Table2 on (Table1.f2_id = Table2.f2_id)
   inner join Table3 on (Table2.f3_id = Table3.f3_id)

where (Table3.tbl3_code = 'value')

 )
```

Is my update SQL correct or there is better way to write it ?

Comment: Short recap of the duplicate: use [`MERGE`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-merge.html)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I dont know which table to use as a source, if possible give me an answer using Merge

Comment: what about `update table1 ... where (tbl1_f1 is null) and ( 'value' = ( select Table3.tbl3_code from Table3, Table2 where (Table2.f3_id = Table3.f3_id) and  (Table1.f2_id = Table2.f2_id) ) )` ? If this works (that is, inner select always returns singleton, not zero-rows and not many-rows) it might be better or worse than for-select approach of @rstrelba  (you would have to check and compare PLANs and statement statistics for both on your real data)

Comment: @Wel For the source of merge you can use a select as well

Answer (score 1):

```
execute block
as
declare id bigint;
begin
for select tbl1_id
from table1 
   inner join Table2 on (Table1.f2_id = Table2.f2_id)
   inner join Table3 on (Table2.f3_id = Table3.f3_id)
where (Table3.tbl3_code = 'value')
into :id
do update table1 set tbl1_f1 = 1 where (tbl1_f1 is null)
and table1.tbl1_id =:id;

end;
```

Comment: better move `tbl1_f1 is null` check into inside for-select loop